# Centering li elements of an unordered list using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

My ul has a few free li elements which have images in them and I wanted to center those li elements. I tried to find the solution but am facing a hard time to figuring it out. Could you guys suggest some way of doing it. I was thinking of surrounding the ul with a div, and then centering the ul within the div. Do you think that will work? I also wanted to mention that I wanted to maintain the float left property.

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="thumb">
  <li><img src="photos/home9.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="photos/home1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="photos/home3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="photos/home4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.thumb {
list-style: none;
width: 90%;
margin: auto;
height: 750px;  
}

.thumb li {
float: left;
}

.thumb li img {
height: 200px; 
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
padding: 5px;
background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the **float:left;** then you will need to add a container **div** to the **ul** with a **width** and **margin:auto;**

Here is how:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jneEq

But this will only cause the ul to appear centred if you set the width exactly to the width of the images.

Comment: No problem! Note that the width of the new container includes the padding and border you have around the images.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your li's `inline-blocks`, instead of `float`. In short, doing so will cause your li's to take up space like a block element, but behave like an inline element, which will make them follow a `text-align:center;` that you will want to add to your ul element. Visually, they will appear sort of like a "centered float," for lack of a better term.

Here's the CSS and a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/RTt8g/):

```
.thumb {
  list-style: none;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 750px;
  text-align:center; /* center inline and inline-block elements */
}

.thumb li {
  display:inline-block; /* no float; by making these inline-blocks they will center b/c their parent is text-align:center */
}

.thumb li img {
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the images, then you will need to add this:

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

If you center the ul which is a child for the div, the ul will be placed in the center, but the `li` items won't be. So it would be better if you place the list items in the center, you can moreover add the `margin: 0; padding: 0` to the `ul` too! as

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I hope this way you will have the images placed in center when there is no other margins and paddings! :)

You can try all this here: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/b29D8/

Answer (score 0):

can you check this up ?

I have updated the css to use `text-align: center;`

```
.thumb li {
  text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XZt2b/

Answer (score 0):

If you have no luck with the other options, you can use:

```
li {
   display:block;
   width: 200px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will make sure they are always in the middle of the available space.

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to remove

```
.thumb li {
    float: left;
}
```

As well as consider Afzaal's answer

http://jsfiddle.net/EbCZ4/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I wanted to keep the float left property

Comment: I don't think this will work with the float left property in there.

Comment: Hmm, ok, is there any other suggestion apart from using a ul.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to set `display: block; margin: auto` on the `<img>` elements.

http://codepen.io/jessegavin/pen/jBpdo

```
.thumb {
  list-style: none;
  width: 90%;
  height: 750px;  
}

.thumb li img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to make it with a little bit jquery, try it:

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$('.thumb > ul > li').each(function(){
    totalWidth+= $(this).width();
});
$('.thumb > ul').css('width', totalWidth + 'px');
```

Here is full [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/hDdzm/)